# Mongodb aggregate get total count after multiple match and lookup stages

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get total count of records after multiple match and lookup stages. I know that count attribute gives count against 1 matchs stage but what if i have two or more match stages inside my aggregate and between those match stages i also have lookup stages. How can I get exact count? Here is my aggregate.

```
pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      statusRepositoryId: new ObjectId(filter.statusRepositoryId),
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Parcel",
      localField: "parcelId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "parcel",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$parcel",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ParcelStatus",
      localField: "parcel._id",
      foreignField: "parcelId",
      as: "parcel.parcelStatuses",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "CustomerData",
      localField: "parcel.customerDataId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "parcel.customerData",
    },
  },
  { $unwind: "$parcel.customerData" },
  {
    $match: {
      "parcel.customerData.cityId": new ObjectId(filter.cityId),
    },
  },
  { $count: "count" },
];
```

Data

```
[
  {
    "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
    "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-18T14:56:45.587Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-18T14:56:45.587Z",
    "statusRepositoryId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2de",
    "reason": "cancelled",
    "checkboxDataArray": [
      "Refused to receive the parcel"
    ],
    "riderId": "5f45ffc61ffedf439ac610c8",
    "image": "https://swyft-attachments-v1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/MarkParcelStatus/2ac5fe70-f9bf-11ea-86b3-111fc7495e46.jpeg",
    "parcel": {
      "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
      "createdAt": "2020-09-14T14:12:37.835Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-09-18T15:36:55.525Z",
      "vendorParcelId": "272837",
      "orderType": "COD",
      "boxType": "Flyer",
      "amount": 2550,
      "qty": 2,
      "originCityId": "5ee134da0138634c27a6e1dd",
      "pickupLocationId": "PL-687422",
      "description": "DPL20 555 Suit UPC: LA01611-Std-MLT UPC: custom:Lawn custom:2 Pc Shirt | Lawn Dupatta  UPC: 1DPL20 550 Suit UPC: LA01606-Std-YLW UPC: custom:Lawn custom:2 Pc Shirt | Lawn Dupatta  UPC: 1",
      "weight": 1,
      "additionalServices": [],
      "isPickedUp": true,
      "paymentMode": "cash",
      "isProcessed": true,
      "isOnline": true,
      "customerDataId": "5f5f7a55df396137fdd64cd9",
      "currentStatusId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2d8",
      "previousStatusId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2de",
      "loadsheetId": "LS-005966",
      "zoneAreaId": "ZONE_NOT_DEFINED",
      "parcelStatuses": [
        {
          "_id": "5f5f7a55df396137fdd64cda",
          "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
          "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
          "createdAt": "2020-09-14T14:12:37.842Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-09-14T14:12:37.842Z",
          "statusRepositoryId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2e1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f631ca20ecb1f33c089e87e",
          "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
          "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
          "createdAt": "2020-09-17T08:21:54.750Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-09-17T08:21:54.750Z",
          "statusRepositoryId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2dd"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f6382057e4a061b28f9c23d",
          "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
          "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
          "createdAt": "2020-09-17T15:34:29.687Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-09-17T15:34:29.687Z",
          "statusRepositoryId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2d8"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f64426caa7f835b423dc2aa",
          "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
          "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
          "createdAt": "2020-09-18T05:15:24.439Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-09-18T05:15:24.439Z",
          "statusRepositoryId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2e3",
          "riderId": "5f45ffc61ffedf439ac610c8"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f64426daa7f835b423dc2c9",
          "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
          "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
          "createdAt": "2020-09-18T05:15:25.314Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-09-18T05:15:25.314Z",
          "statusRepositoryId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2e2",
          "riderId": "5f45ffc61ffedf439ac610c8"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f64caadee163f6696f8439a",
          "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
          "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
          "createdAt": "2020-09-18T14:56:45.587Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-09-18T14:56:45.587Z",
          "statusRepositoryId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2de",
          "reason": "cancelled",
          "checkboxDataArray": [
            "Refused to receive the parcel"
          ],
          "riderId": "5f45ffc61ffedf439ac610c8",
          "image": "https://swyft-attachments-v1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/MarkParcelStatus/2ac5fe70-f9bf-11ea-86b3-111fc7495e46.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f64d417cb02f27072f144c8",
          "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
          "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
          "createdAt": "2020-09-18T15:36:55.480Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-09-18T15:36:55.480Z",
          "statusRepositoryId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2d8",
          "adminManagerId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2d4"
        }
      ],
      "customerData": {
        "firstName": "Riffat",
        "email": "riffatfhm@yahoo.com",
        "lastName": "faheem ",
        "address": "476A dhoke gujran misrial road Rawalpindi ",
        "addressLocation": {
          "lat": 33.601617,
          "lng": 72.9913365
        },
        "cityId": "5ee134da0138634c27a6e1dc",
        "parcelId": "RWP900001170670",
        "vendorId": "5eeb04af35109774c533cb55",
        "createdAt": "2020-09-14T14:12:37.833Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-09-17T08:22:06.456Z",
        "customerId": "5f5f7a55df396137fdd64cd8",
        "customer": {
          "phone": "3345174367",
          "createdAt": "2020-09-14T14:12:37.827Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-09-14T14:12:37.827Z",
          "id": "5f5f7a55df396137fdd64cd8"
        },
        "id": "5f5f7a55df396137fdd64cd9"
      },
      "id": "RWP900001170670"
    },
    "id": "5f64caadee163f6696f8439a"
  }
]
```

Comment: Help!! IAnyone?

Comment: What is not working with that last stage of `$count`?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti The last stage does give me count but I don't think that its the right number of count because for the first match stage it gives 263K+ count but for the last match it gives me 206K+ count. Which according to my database records feels to like they are wrong. The total count should be considerably less like 80K+ records. There is no other way for me to get the exact count that's why I am doubtful of the count that I am getting.

Comment: Also its very slow. I want this to give me count in 3 or 4 seconds max

Comment: 263K out of a population of how many?   How fast does the first match go?   And `parcelStatus` is not used for anything?   If you really need parcel status are you sure `parcelId` has an index on it?  All the other lookups use `_id` and of course that is autoindexed.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I don't need parcelStatus so i have removed it and then ran the aggregate and got same count but it took about 22 seconds which is too much. 263K from first match out of a population of about 1.2M+.

Comment: How fast is just the first match?   No other lookups.

Comment: instantly. it takes only 1 or 2 seconds max

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti do you think my aggregate is correct? Don't you think that there should be anyother way to get the correct count like get the first match first and then group the result of maybe use facet and then get the remaining count out after the second match? Or am i already doing the right thing?

Comment: You probably have an explosion of data due to `unwind`.   Tell us a little about the shapes in the main collection, the Parcel collection, and the CustomerData collection.

Comment: I am trying to show data here but even one object is way too much big to show here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221702/discussion-between-ahsan-nissar-and-buzz-moschetti).

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti please join me in the room

Answer (score 0):

The OP probably wants the count of items in the main collection where the `stateRepositoryId` equals something and, linking thru the joins, where the `cityId` equals something.   In pseudoSQL:

```
select count(*) from maintable
left outer join parceltable._id = maintable.parcelId
left outer join customertable._id = parceltable.customerDataID
where maintable.stateRepositoryID = 'ABC'
and customertable.cityID = 'NYC'
```

Assume the main collection is `foo`, the parcel collection is `foo_parcel`, and the customer data collection is `foo_cust`.  Here's a way to use the `pipeline` feature of `$lookup` to do a *nested lookup* :

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {statusRepoId: "B"}}

,{$lookup: {
        from: "foo_parcel",
        let: { pcl: "$parcelID" },
        pipeline: [

    // effectively, this is:                                                 
        // LEFT OUTER JOIN foo_parcel._id = foo.parcelID                         
        {$match: {$expr: {$and: [
                                 {$eq: [ "$_id", "$$pcl" ]}
                                  ]}}},

        {$lookup: {
          from: "foo_cust",
          let: { cid: "$customerDataID" },

          // effectively, this is:                                               
          // LEFT OUTER JOIN foo_cust._id = foo_cust.customerDataID              
          // WHERE foo_cust = 'NYC'                                              
          pipeline: [
                    {$match: {$expr: {$and: [
                    {$eq: [ "$_id", "$$cid" ]}
                   ,{$eq: [ "$cityId", "NYC" ]}
                          ]}}}
                   ],
          as: "Z"}}

          // eliminate empty left outer joins                                    
          ,{$match: {$expr: { $gt: [ {$size: "$Z"}, 0 ] }}}

        ],
        as: "Z2"}}

        // eliminate empty left outer joins                                      
        ,{$match: {$expr: { $gt: [ {$size: "$Z2"}, 0 ] }}}

,{$count: "n"}
                      ]);
```

Comment: please tell me where are you adding cityId filter? I need to use cityId in the match

Comment: I changed NYC to my cityId and change statusRepositoryId to my statusId and also changed the collections name to their actual names and ran this aggregate but it gave me an empty array

Comment: Probably one of the field names is a little different in your model.   I tested this agg against a small amount of test data.

Comment: yes you are right and after fixing the field names i ran the aggregate and it gave me count but i got the count after 40 seconds... this is too much time

Comment: Parcel collection contains more than 2M+ records or maybe 3M+. The main collection on which the aggregate is running usually returns from 30K to 300K+ records for any any that is passed to stausRepositoryId so against that data a parcel is fetched and then another customerData collection is added inside parcel collection and then a match stage which pretty increased counting time exponentially .

Comment: Since my backend is in loopbackjs I am unable to use a loopback filter because where clause does not work inside include as desired

Comment: If the first match to get 236K is instant but the lookups expand it to 40 seconds, I suspect something is not indexed.